# Android Drawable background randomly changes color to black or white

Tags: android, button, background, drawable

In our app we are experiencing some weird behaviour with the colour of one of our drawables. We're using it as a background to a button in many places in our code, the background drawable is only being set in the xml layout and we're not applying any tint or colour filter dynamically in Java.

Seemingly randomly the drawable colour is either white or black, and its like this on all places where we use it -> this sounds to me like either the drawable is corrupted during build time(occurs in debug and release builds, tried cleaning project). It's not device or os specific either, tried on many devices and still occurs randomly...
Help?

The offending background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/default_corner_radius"/>
</shape>
```

The button using the background drawable

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left_drawable"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
        android:text="@string/the_string"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/buttons"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please post an output image and your expected image.